# How to select different keyboard types in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

Is there a way to select a specific keyboard type (for email, urls, etc.) in QML for text fields? (e.g. for iOS UIKeyboardType)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can exploit the [`inputMethodHints`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-textfield.html#inputMethodHints-prop) property. Directly from the documentation:

> Provides hints to the **input method** about the **expected content** of the text field and **how it should operate**. The value is a bit-wise combination of flags, or `Qt.ImhNone` if no hints are set. The default value is `Qt.ImhNone`.

Indeed, looking at the sources, these hints calls the native keyboards (see the code at the bottom [here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/plugins/platforms/ios/quiview_textinput.mm?id=ad120dbf13ddb7bff26e4489fbd0333facc1d38f#n584) - `Textinput` is used by `TextField` internally).

Hence, to define a `TextField` which accepts only digits, you can define it like this:

```
TextField {
    width: 100
    height: 30
    inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhDigitsOnly
}
```

Depending on the device (`Android` or `iOS`, tablet or phone) you'll get the highlighted numbers or just a numerical keypad.

Same applies to the other hints you have cited which are covered by `Qt.ImhEmailCharactersOnly` and `Qt.ImhUrlCharactersOnly`, respectively.